# Retrieving tablenames from database in string formatted text

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, ssms

I have a query like this

```
@"SELECT 
                                               TABLE_NAME
                                              AS
                                               TABLES
                                            FROM 
                                               INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
                                           WHERE 
                                               CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
                                             AND
                                               TABLE_NAME <> 'dtProperties'
                                        ORDER BY
                                               TABLE_NAME";
```

Is there any way to convert the tabular form to string formatted form when retrieving list of tables from this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via .NET it is neither - that is just the SSMS display. Based on the previous questions, it sounds like you are just having difficulties reading this column into strings;

Perhaps just something like:

```
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    using(var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand()) {
        cmd.CommandText = @"
            SELECT TABLE_NAME
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
            WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
            AND TABLE_NAME <> 'dtProperties'
            ORDER BY TABLE_NAME";
        conn.Open();

        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
            while (reader.Read()) {
                list.Add(reader.GetString(0));
            }
        }
    }
```

(tested locally; works fine)

If you want something delimited, then perhaps:

```
string s = string.Join("|", list);
```

Or something involving a `StringBuilder` (newlines in this example):

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    using(var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand()) {
        cmd.CommandText = @"
            SELECT TABLE_NAME
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
            WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
            AND TABLE_NAME <> 'dtProperties'
            ORDER BY TABLE_NAME";
        conn.Open();

        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
            while (reader.Read()) {
                sb.AppendLine(reader.GetString(0));
            }
        }
    }
    string s = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this helps?

```
string[] myObjArray = new string[DataTable1.Rows.Count];

DataTable1.Rows.CopyTo(myObjArray, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean with formatted form.
You can retrieve a string with all table names with following sql statement:

```
declare @out varchar(max)
set @out = ''
select @out = @out + table_name + char(10) + char(13) from information_schema.table_constraints
where constraint_type = 'PRIMARY KEY'
and table_name <> 'dtProperties'
order by table_name

select @out
```